# Is NSTimer expensive?

Tags: iphone

I am using about 20 `UIImageView`s of small airplane images (50x50 pixels) doing simple animation on the iPhone screen. The animation is done by shifting the `UIImageView` center property at timer interval.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES]
```

What is the best practice: create one `NSTimer` and loop the 20 `UIImageView`s to set the center property when timer fired? Or should I just create one `NSTimer` per `UIImageView` object? Is `NSTimer` resource expensive?

Comment: I am creating PlaneView object deriving from UIImageView. The timer is run within each PlaneView object instead of the within the ViewController that has the PlaneView as subview. I am still experimenting...:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's that resource intensive, but common sense would seem to dictate that using 1 timer is probably better than 20.

Looks like your timer is set to fire 100 times per second, which seems a bit excessive. Do you animate each sprite at every timer firing?  Might want to try firing 20-30 times per second instead (or maybe even less).

You might want to look into the built in view animation functions as well.  Seems like they would probably work very well for what you are doing.

Comment: At at rate, I could imagine that the Objective-C overhead can be quite expensive.

Comment: Regarding firing rate: LCD's generally refresh at 60 Hz, so trying to animate more frequently than that is in fact excessive.

Answer (score 3):

you could try both and use the built in profiling tools that ship with Xcode to gauge resource usage.

Answer (score 0):

**Timers are actually PRETTY EXPENSIVE, energy-wise.**

Every nanosecond that the OS (or apps running on it) are not doing something, the CPU is sleeping in one of several low-power state modes. Waking the system from an idle state incurs an energy cost when the CPU and other systems are awakened from their low-power, idle states. If a timer causes the system to wake, it incurs that cost. The more frequently your timer fires, the higher the energy cost. On mobile devices, it can affect materially battery life.

In that sense, it is much more efficient to wake the system once, do all your work, then let it sleep again for as many nanosecs as possible. Going back to your example, if you profile this, it should be more efficient to use 1 timer rather than 20 timers, each firing 100 times / sec.

Later OS versions allow you to specify a tolerance (in %). This allows the system to group timers together and execute them at the same wake event, to save power. It seems what you are doing is not time critical (in a real-time execution kind of sense), so permitting a tolerance (e.g. 10%) should help.

Example: `[myTimer setTolerace:0.3];`

More about timer tolerance here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attempting to have a Timer synchronized to the screen redraw (i.e. firing 60x a second), a better solution would be to use `CADisplayLink`, which fires as on screen redraw and is built for this purpose.

```
let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(displayLinkFired))
displayLink.add(to: .main, forMode: .default) // attach to the main run loop

@objc func displayLinkFired() {
   // update image view's here
}
```